# How to get image size of multiple pages pdf on mac terminal?

Tags: macos, pdf, terminal

I would like to get image size of multiple pages pdf on Mac terminal. (I want to know that is portrait or landscape.)
(the information of in the red circle of following images)

I tried "sips" command (-g pixelWidth).
But the command shows only 1st page information.

I need the information of 2nd page or later.

[information what I want to get by terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rI6SM.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import os
import Quartz as qt
PATH = 'hoge.pdf'

fileprovider = qt.CGDataProviderCreateWithFilename(PATH)
pdffile = qt.CGPDFDocumentCreateWithProvider(fileprovider)
pagenumber = qt.CGPDFDocumentGetNumberOfPages(pdffile)
pageinforef = qt.CGPDFDocumentGetPage(pdffile, pagenumber)
pageRect = qt.CGPDFPageGetBoxRect(pageinforef, qt.kCGPDFMediaBox)
width = qt.NSWidth(pageRect)
```

run python file in terminal